# WiFi is unstable on Dell Inspirion 42100

Tags: wireless, ath9k

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS along side on my Windows 8.1 Dell. I then upgraded to Windows 10. At first it worked great but now Ubuntu can only connect to WiFi after running Windows for about 15-30 mins. lspci shows Network Controller: Atheros QCA9565/ AR9565 Network Adapter. nm-tool shows wlan0 802.11 WiFi, Driver ath9k. When WiFi is working and I plug in my TP Link WN722n (which needs driver ath9k_htc to operate). The TP Link WN722n is shown as wlan2 phy1 and I'm able to capture traffic in both monitor and promiscuous mode so I know the ath9k driver is funtioning properly. What do I need to do to maintain constant WiFi connection while using Ubuntu 14.04LTS? Should I upgrade to 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, after going to Ubuntu Help in the settings tab I was instructed to check my router setup. So I did. I enabled then disabled DNS Override and disabled then enabled the UPnp. Then restated my laptop. Ran Ubuntu and WHALA!!! WiFi is connected without having to run Windows for 1/2hour first. I'll repost if the signal is lost again.